# Solving an ODE via Fourier transforms - solution not integrable

Tags: fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

I am trying to solve an ODE via Fourier transforms,

$$ f^{\prime \prime} = -f $$

Naively following the usual approach I get

$$- \xi ^2 \hat {f} = - \hat{f} \\
(\xi^2 -1 ) \hat{f} = 0 \\
\hat{f} = 0$$
which seems a dead end.

The solution is $\sin (x) $ and is not integrable and its Fourier transform exists in the distributional sense

$$ \widehat{\sin(x)} = \sqrt{2 \pi} \,\frac{\delta (\xi - 1 )- \delta (\xi + 1)}{2i} $$
and it seems the relationship

$$ \hat {f ^{\prime}} = i \xi \hat{f} $$
does apply, if I consider the Fourier Transforms of $\sin$ and $\cos$. Probably taking excessive freedoms, the numerator equals $0$ unless $\xi = 1,-1$, and then the $i$ factor makes just things right with respect to $
\widehat{\cos} (x)
$.

So in the "naive"calculation above it is the division by the factor $1-\xi^2$ that is to blame: nonsense comes from the division by $0$.

However, I would like to see how this specific calculation is to be rigorously handled.

Comment: Is is not easier to use the Ansatz $f(x)=\exp(\lambda x)$ ? 

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch, definitely easier, but sometimes the awkward way is more interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distributional solution to $(\xi^2 -1 ) \hat{f} = 0$ is not $\hat{f}\equiv 0$ but $\hat{f}(\xi) = A\,\delta(\xi+1)+B\,\delta(\xi-1),$ where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

Comment: thanks a lot. I thought I clarified that I understand $\hat{f} = 0$ is not the solution. I probably express myself really badly, I will try to re-phrase my question.

Comment: @Anaedonist. That was clear since you wrote "which seems a dead end". Maybe I should also clarify why the distributional solutions to $(\xi^2-1)\hat{f}=0$ are $\hat{f}(\xi) = A\,\delta(\xi+1) + B\,\delta(\xi-1).$

Comment: That would be great, I would like to see how the ODE is rigorously solved using Fourier Transforms. At the moment I intuitively see what is going on, but would love to see a rigorous approach using distributions, thanks

Comment: It's a general theorem in distribution theory that if $g$ is a smooth function with zeroes of order $n_k$ at $a_k$ then $gu=0$ has solutions $u = \sum_k c_k \delta_{a_k}^{(n_k)}.$ A simple example is $xu=0$ with solutions $u=c\delta$. This can be understood from
$$\int \left(x\,c\delta(x)\right) \varphi(x)\,dx = \int c\delta(x)\,x\varphi(x)\,dx = 0\varphi(0) = 0.$$

Comment: thanks I will look it up